# Send Audio File with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, api, axios

How to send an audio file to an API with Axios?

I'm programming in JavaScript - React Native and I'm stuck on that part.

I want to know how I do this through a script running with node, not html.

```
var audioFile = fs.createReadStream("./Welcome.wav")
var form = new FormData();

form.append("file", audioFile);

axios.post('https://speech2text-vitor.herokuapp.com/name', 
    form,
    {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
    }
)
.then(result => {
    console.log(result.data)
})
```

Note: I'm running with nodejs

API in Python:

```
app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/name", )
async def post_name(file: UploadFile=File(...)):
    return file.filename
```

Comment: Any progress?
What do you use as `fs`?